# R - plot map with ggmap using geom column

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I would like to plot a map from a data.frame using ggmap. I have been doing this, but now I does not have Lat and Long columns, I only have a geom column of the type:

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

Is it possible to use the geom column as a argument in the ggmap() function? or is it possible to transform a geom column in Lat / Long columns so than I can use the following code?

```
ggmap(map)+geom_polygon(data, aes(lon, lat))
```

Comment: Where does your data come from? Do you have any idea how it is encoded?

Comment: Depends entirely on how your `geom` column is encoded.

Comment: As enconded do you mean geographic SRID? If yes, my data is enconded as 29193.

Comment: It looks like your data may be stored as Well-Known Binary. If that is the case, the Simple Features for R package may help. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html